# overwriting objects in arraylist when adding temp object

Tags: java, arraylist

```
package accounttest;

/**
 * Customer --- A class that stores the customer name and customer usage and provides a method, calcUsage,
 *              to calculate the price to the customer based on the customer usage
 * 
 * @author s0267955, William Rogers
 */
public class Account {
    public static String custName; //Stores the customer name
    public static int custUsage;  //Stores the customers usage
    public static int custAccountNumber;  //Stores the customers account number

    public Account(){  //No use of a constructor
    }

    public void setName(String name){  //Sets the name of the customer
        custName = name;
    }
    public String getName(){  //Gets the name of the customer
        return custName;
    }
    public void setUsage(int usage){  //Sets the usage for the customer
        custUsage = usage;
    }
    public int getUsage(){  //Gets the usage of the customer
        return custUsage;
    }
    public void setAccountNumber(int accountNumber){//Sets the account number
        custAccountNumber = accountNumber;
    }
    public int getAccountNumber(){  //Gets the account number of the customer
        return custAccountNumber;
    }
}
```

.

```
public class AccountTest {


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int TOTAL_ACCOUNTS = 2;  // The total number of accounts
    ArrayList<Account> account= new ArrayList<Account>(); 

    for(int x = 0;x<TOTAL_ACCOUNTS;x++){  
        Account tempAccount = new Account(); 
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        System.out.print( "Enter the name for Customer #"+(x+1)+": ");
        tempAccount.setName(input.nextLine()); 
        System.out.print( "Enter the account number for "+tempAccount.getName()+":");
        tempAccount.setAccountNumber(input.nextInt());  //gets the account number for the temp account
        System.out.print( "Enter the internet usage for Customer #"+(x+1)+": ");
        tempAccount.setUsage(input.nextInt()); //retrieves customer usage for the temp account object

        account.add(tempAccount); //Adds the account object to the array

    }

    for(Account x:account){ 
        System.out.print(x + " ");
        System.out.print(x.getName()+", ");
        System.out.print(x.getAccountNumber()+", ");
        System.out.print(x.getUsage());
        System.out.println();
    }
   }
}
```

RESULTS:

```
accounttest.Account@5c647e05 Obj2, 2, 50
accounttest.Account@33909752 Obj2, 2, 50
```

**Question:** Why are the objects getting overwritten? I need the program to be able to add new objects, but all the addresses are overwritten with what ever object was added last

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Adding to @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ, please provide an input and an expected output aswell, when the question is asked.

Comment: Why are the objects getting overwritten?  I need the program to be able to add new objects, but all the addresses are overwritten with what ever object was added last.

Comment: Sorry, was expecting to have like this:

Comment: I did test it, and it doesn´t overwrite them.

Comment: accounttest.Account@5c647e05 Obj1, 1, 1
accounttest.Account@33909752 Obj2, 2, 50

Comment: In `Account`,  are all your members `static` perchance? They _are_ different objects (`5c647e05` vs `33909752`) but with the same data.

Comment: **Note:** Declare your scanner outside for loop.

Comment: So, your print out is all unique objects?  Any idea why mine would be different?  Is it possible the problem is with the class?

Comment: @WilliamRogers show `Account`. Have you checked for `static` members?

Comment: Kindly show us your `Account` class.

Comment: @WilliamRogers in your Account class, are the variables you are accessing (with the getter) declared as static?

Comment: public static void setName(String name){  //Sets the name of the customer
        custName = name;
    }
    public static String getName(){  //Gets the name of the customer
        return custName;
    }

Comment: Kindly edit your question and add your `Account` class.

Comment: Sorry, new to this, I've added it now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by **@BoristheSpider**, remove **static** from your variables.

```
public class Account {
    public String custName; //Stores the customer name
    public int custUsage;  //Stores the customers usage
    public int custAccountNumber;  //Stores the customers account number
    ...
```

**Note:** Declare your scanner outside for loop.

Comment: Ahhh, I see.  I used code from another app and it barked at me to include those statics.  I just added them again.  I clearly need to learn how to use static.  Thanks for your help!